# What is the genre of French popular songs of the 1960s?

Tags: genre, terminology

Many songs that are still popular in France today date from the 1960s with for example Joe Dassin, Charles Aznavour, Boris Vian, etc.

To which genre can we associate these artists? The Wikipedia page in French gives "French song" which is not really satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably do mean [**chanson**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_France#Chanson).
…tough to use as a search term because it literally just translates as 'song'. It is a style in itself. People stretch the name to 'chanson Française' in an attempt to differentiate the term.

'French lyrical ballad' might be a more descriptive translation, but as with many terms, the association is greater than the literal meaning. What's "rock"? A large lump of stone?

Frenchly did a good article on it recently, sweeping easily from its beginnings in medieval times to its current state of affairs.
[La Chanson Française, the Genre that Never Dies: How the French Perfected Sad Girl Pop](https://frenchly.us/la-chanson-francaise-the-genre-that-never-dies-how-the-french-perfected-sad-girl-pop/)